# Disabling "this can only be used in an object context" notification for PHP

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anyone know how to disable the `$this can only be used in an object context` error in the problems tab or to properly configure VS Code ?

There is a lot of red underlining code in my php view files.

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem. There is an open thread on the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/felixfbecker/php-language-server/issues/536).